# Google Maps will not show unless fixed height is defined

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a column layout framework, and I can't seem to get Google Maps to work with it. It shows fine if i define the height on the map-canvas to be i.e. 100px. However, I want it to be 100% of the height on 6 columns, and this will not work as it apparently sets the height (no matter what percentage i set) to 0.

The code i have is:

```
<div class="col l6">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

and the javascript is from the simple example on their website.

I have set the height to 100% on `<html>`and `<body>` as per their documentation, but it does not work anyways.

My question is this: How do I ensure that the map is shown without having to style the #map-canvas with a specific x pixel height?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to set the height to 100% on both the div with the columns and the map-canvas div.

Comment: does the 6 column have height and width? Sorry, I removed my previous comment, I saw your last sentence first paragraph.

Comment: See [Using a percentage height for the map div](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have battled with this kind of thing recently when using Bootstrap UI.

I had to add this in my case, see if it helps...

```
#map-canvas {
    width:100%;
    height:calc(100% - 0px);
}
```

Comment: It almost does! I had to modify it just a bit to fit my needs, so the actual code is: top:64px; height:calc(100% - 64px); position:absolute; width: 49.43%.

Comment: aha, glad it helped, i tore my hair out trying to find ways and had never see that calc based way in css before.

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this until recently, the thing is that you actually need to make a full page just for the map (the one on the documentation [getting started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=es) will do). And then use that with an `<iframe>` on the actual page that you want it to go. Then you just work with the iframe width and height.